# Long/Short strategy only shows close entry order for long

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

A newbie here. I am working on a strategy long/short. When i run my strategy the Long positions are closed as expected but the Short positions i believe are not. Because i have the fees setup to USD per order i want to make sure that every market order is opened/closed so i can back test my strategy. My code as follows.

```
    hist = macd - signal
if (hist > 0.15)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
if (hist < -0.15)
    strategy.close("Long")
if (hist < -0.15)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short")
if (hist > 0.15)
    strategy.close("Short")
```

[image: Chart]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behaivour as your conditions in fact defined as

```
hist = macd - signal

if (hist > 0.15)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    strategy.close("Short")
    
if (hist < -0.15)
    strategy.close("Long")
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, comment="Short")
```

So when you enter Short position in `(hist < -0.15)` condition,
at the next bars, when `if (hist > 0.15)` is true you will revert your `Short` position by `strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works as expected but still with the same behavior. I have set up an alert and when the Long position closes and Short opens i receive 2 alerts one saying my position is now "0" for Long and "number of contracts" for Short. But when Short closes and Long opens i only receive one alert Long buy "number of contracts" and no sell position "0" for Short. Since i ma trying to implement a bot with Finandy i assume i should receive 4 alerts and not 3 if it makes sense. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Try to put `strategy.close("Short")` before long entry.